# how glassfish generate xsd with class and annotation?

Tags: java, web-services, xsd, wsdl

I have created a new method 
    @WebMethod(operationName = "getTot")
    public String getTot

when i do
     https://host/webserviceMachin/toto?wsdl

```
it succeeded because i can read in this file
message name="getTot" ...
```

but i don't know how the former computer programming have succeeded to add xsd :
xsd:import namespace="http://machinn/Wrappers 
schemaLocation="https://host:443/webserviceMachin/toto?xsd=1

in the https://host/webserviceMachin/toto?wsdl

I don't how glassfish recognize "xsd" or annotation xsd, there is no file (physical) xsd. There is a toto.wsdl but it is not used by glassfish, i changed it and the https://host:443/webserviceMachin/toto.wsdl don't change, it is somewhere in the code, i have searched for annotation,

Do you have some idea...?

Comment: During the deployment glassfish search annotation @webmethod and "other things for xsd" (what i search), there are not at all file.xsd or .wsdl. I hope it is clearer.

Comment: I progress just with @XmlType(namespace="http://machin/Wrappers") public class wrapper<K, V> , i must use this class if not it is not generated